# Python 3: Crear función que identifique si unas coordenadas están o no dentro de un vector de puntos

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, condiciones, python-requests

Buenos días a todos por acá: para comenzar aclarar que soy bastante nuevo en python. Actualmente estoy tomando un curso en el que me piden:

Escriba una función `def estaEn(esquinauno=(0,0), esquinados=(0,0), prueba=[]):` que devuelva `True/False` si un número de puntos está dentro o fuera de un unas coordenadas especificadas `(a1, b1), (a2, b2)`. La función debe aceptar tres parámetros:

1.El primer parámetro es un conjunto de coordenadas que define una de las "esquinas" de una figura `(a1, b1)`,

2. el segundo parámetro es también un conjunto de coordenadas que define la segunda "esquina" `(a2, b2)`,
3. el tercer conjunto de coordenadas define el área que se está probando, es decir, el valor de prueba.

Me dan estos puntos de prueba:

```
estaEn((0,0), (5,5), [(1,1), (0,0), (5,5)]) #debería ser True
estaEn((0,0), (5,5), [(1,1), (0,0), (5,6)]) #debería ser False
estaEn((0,0), (5,5), []) #debería ser False --> lista vacía.
```

Yo he intentado correr algo como esto:

```
#Función base dada
def estaEn(esquinauno=(0,0), esquinados=(0,0), puntos=[]):
#definición del índex de mis puntos:
  a1,b1=esquinauno[0],esquinauno[1]
  a2,b2=esquinados[0],esquinados[1]
#como son 3 puntos a probar intento indexar 3 pares de puntos
  a,b,c=puntos[0][0], puntos[0][0], puntos[0][0]
#Intento hacer un if para verificar si el valor es nulo o vacío.
  if len(puntos) == 0:
     return False
  elif(a >= a1 and a <= a2):
      return True
  elif(a >= a2 and a <= a1):
      return True
  elif(b >= b1 and b <= b2):
      return True
  elif(b >= b2 and b <= b1):
      return True
  elif(c >= c2 and c <= c1):
      return True
  elif(c >= c2 and c <= c1):
      return True
  else:
      return False
```

Pero cuando lo intento obtengo

```
estaEn((0,0), (5,5), [(1,1), (0,0), (5,5)]) ---> True
estaEn((0,0), (5,5), [(1,1), (0,0), (5,6)]) ---> True
estaEn((0,0), (5,5), []) 
----> a,b,c=pointList[0][0], pointList[0][0], pointList[0][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Alguien que entienda mejor el tema que me dé una mano. No sé si quizá haya una forma más intuitiva y fácil de hacer lo mismo y yo no la esté viendo.

Quedaré muy agradecido a cualquiera que me desee ayudar.
Saludos a todos.

Comment: te debería bastar con el operador de pertenencia `in`, por ejemplo `return esquinauno in puntos and esquinados in puntos`

Comment: @Christian Son coordenadas. Los puntos pueden estar "dentro" de la caja. Ejemplo: `estaEn((0,0), (5,5), [(2,2), (3,3), (4,4)])`

Comment: @CandidMoe aaa.... ok, lo había interpretado mal >_<.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, recibes una lista pero no procesas sus elementos: las variables `a, b, c` tienen todas el mismo valor, que vendría siendo la coordena X del primero elemento en la lista.

Segundo, para revisar si (x, y) está dentro del área definida por (ax, ay) (bx, by), tienes que chequear dos condiciones:

```
ax <= x <= bx
ay <= y <= by
```

en cambio, retornas `True` sin verificar que la segunda condición se cumpla.

#### Solución

```
def enCaja(a, b, punto):
    return (a[0] <= punto[0] <= b[0]) and (a[1] <= punto[1] <= b[1])

def estaEn(esquinauno, esquinados, puntos):
    for punto in puntos:
        if not enCaja(esquinauno, esquinados, punto):
            return False
    return len(puntos) > 0
```

Por facilidad hice una función `enCaja` que simplemente chequea un solo punto, y la función `estaEn`, que se encarga de revisar la lista completa.

Esta última función revisa punto por punto. Si un punto está fuera, se retorna de inmediato; no es necesario revisar más.

Si `while` termina, significa que todos los puntos están dentro del área o que la lista está vacia. Eso lo evaluo en el `return` mismo.

#### Demo

```
def enCaja(a, b, punto):
    return (a[0] <= punto[0] <= b[0]) and (a[1] <= punto[1] <= b[1])

def estaEn(esquinauno, esquinados, puntos):
    for punto in puntos:
        if not enCaja(esquinauno, esquinados, punto):
            return False
    return len(puntos) > 0

print(estaEn((0,0), (5,5), [(1,1), (0,0), (5,5)])) #debería ser True
print(estaEn((0,0), (5,5), [(1,1), (0,0), (5,6)])) #debería ser False
print(estaEn((0,0), (5,5), [])) #debería ser False --> lista vacía.
```

produce

```
True
False
False

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Excelente solución, me ayudó a clarificar el tema. 
Saludos.

Comment: @ALRIER_ si la respuesta ha solucionado tu problema, márcala como aceptada